# How to prove that the set of solutions of an IVP is compact using Arzela-Ascoli

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the following Cauchy problem

$${ \begin{cases} y' = f(x,y) \\ y(x_0) =y_0\\\end{cases} }$$

Cauchy-Peano existence theorem guarantees us that if $f(x,y)$ is continuous in a interval $[x_0-a,x_0+a]$ and $[y_0-b,y_0+b]$ there is a solution on the interval $[x_0-h,x_0+h]$ where $h= min(a,\frac{b}{M})$

I want that for all $\alpha \in [x_0 - h,x_0 + h]$ define the set $K(\alpha) =  y(\alpha)$ such that $y:[x_0 - h,x_0 + h] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of our IVP.

Now I want to prove that $K(\alpha)$ is compact

**My attempt**

The question says to use Arzela Ascoli theorem, so to do it we must prove that all functions in $K(\alpha)$ are bounded and equicontinuous.

We know that if we restrict a continuous function to a compact domain, then it attains it maximum and minimum in this compact (smooth functions are continuous), therefore we have a uniformly bounded family of functions. So we have that there exists a $C \gt 0$ such that $y:[x_0 - h,x_0 + h] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is less than C for every x in the domain, by taking $C = sup (y) \forall y \in K(\alpha)$ and $\forall x \in [x_0 - h,x_0 + h] $.

Furthermore we want to prove that the family of functions is equicontinuous, so $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 $$\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that  $\forall x,z \in [x_0 - h,x_0 + h] $ with $|x-z| \lt \delta$ implies $|y(x)-y(z)| \lt \epsilon$. Well, since all of the solutions in $K(\alpha)$ have to agree on the value of $x_0$, and since all the functions are continuous, then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$ $\exists \delta \gt0$ such that $\forall x,z \in [x_0 - h,x_0 + h] $ with $|x-z| \lt \delta$ implies $|y(x)-y(z)| \lt \epsilon$ by just letting $\delta$ be the minimal value that satisfies it in $K(\alpha)$.

So we are in the conditions of Arzela Ascoli theorem, so every sequence in $K(\alpha)$ has a subsequence that converges on it. So by sequential caracterization of compactness, we have proved that $K(\alpha)$
is compact

Is it right? am I going the right way ?is thre some mistake? How could I improve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are exploiting is that the embedding of $C^1$ into $C^0$ is compact. If you have a set that is bounded in $C^1$, then by Arzela-Ascoli it is already compact (or pre-compact) in $C^0$.

So after you found the bound $M$ on $f$ over some rectangle or prism $|x-x_0|\le a$, $\|y-y_0\|\le b$, and restricted the first so that $Mh\le b$, then the set $C$ of functions with graph in the double cone $|x-x_0|\le h$, $\|y(x)-y_0\|\le M|x-x_0|$ is a bounded set and the Picard iterator $P$ maps it into itself, $P[C]\subset C$.

On the other hand, $P[C]\subset C^1$, so per the start it is compact in $C^0$. As the set of solutions is a closed set inside $P[C]$, it is likewise compact.

To remind, $P[y](x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(s,y(s))\,ds$.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear to me now. You were very helpful!